# Bash: Is it better to echo or <<<?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, input, base64

When passing input, which method is better?

```
 > echo 'test' | base64
dGVzdAo=

 > base64 <<< 'test'
dGVzdAo=
```

With variables as well, which method should be use?

```
 > t='test'

 > echo "$t" | base64
dGVzdAo=

 > base64 <<< "$t"
dGVzdAo=
```

Comment: it depends what you want to do. Sometime you wont be able to use a `|` while sometime you wont be able do to without it.

Comment: You'll have to define what 'better' means for you. I would use the former (`echo ... | base64`) because a) it works in all shells, not just advanced ones like `bash` or `zsh` b) it's easier to change to `cat ... | base64` or `dd ... | base64` if that need arise. Generally it's a good idea not to use non-standard features, unless they're **really** useful (the `<(...)` process substitution is an example of that).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<<<` is here-string, a short form of here-document introduced by `zsh` (and the Unix port of `rc`) in the early 90s and copied (with variations) to a number of other shells since.

It's implemented the same way as here-documents. In most shells including `zsh` and `bash`, that's with a deleted temporary file as that's how the Bourne shell (the shell that introduced here-documents in the late 70s) did it.

When you do:

```
cmd <<< 'something'
```

The shell does something like:

```
file=$(mktemp)
printf 'something\n' > "$file"
{
  rm -f -- "$file" && cmd
} < "$file"
```

(except of course all the `mktemp`, `printf`, `rm` is done internally without executing those commands).

Some shells use pipes and a separate process (which can be the main shell process for forked commands or small here-docs/strings) to feed the data. Some shells may revert to using `/dev/null` for empty here-docs (here-strings cannot be empty except in `rc` that doesn't add a newline).

There are several advantages of that in implementations that use temp files.

- no forked process.
- the input is seekable (the command can go back and forth in its input to read data again at different position which it can't do when its input is a pipe). You can't rely on that in a portable `sh` script though.

Some of the drawbacks:

- except in `zsh`, the content cannot contain NUL bytes
- except in `rc`, it's impossible to feed an input that doesn't end in a newline character
- the temp file creation may fail (like when there's no space left in `$TMPDIR` or the `umask` is too restrictive with some implementations).
- the data is stored on permanent storage. Even though the file is deleted before it's `read`, the data may end-up being committed to disk, which mean it could be recovered if one could get hold of the disk.

In:

```
printf '%s\n' "$something" | cmd
```

(here using `printf` instead of `echo` as `echo` can't be used for arbitrary data).

We have two processes running concurrently, one feeding output to the other via a pipe. When `cmd` is builtin or a compound command or function, with `zsh` or AT&T `ksh` or `bash -o lastpipe`, that command is run in the current shell, but otherwise runs in a child process, so things like `echo x | read var` doesn't work.

Some of the advantages of that:

- that's portable (contrary to `<<<`, `<<` is portable)
- that doesn't have the drawbacks of `<<<` mentioned above
- to feed NUL bytes in shells other than `zsh` (`zsh` being the only one that can pass NUL bytes to builtin commands), you can do `printf '\0' | cmd`.

Drawbacks:

- the extra process and the fact that `cmd` is run in a child process in some shells, as already mentioned above
- input not seekable.

Note that if you want the base64 encoding of `test`, that's:

```
printf test | base64
```

Or

```
printf %s "$data" | base64
```

for arbitrary data.

Yours give you the base64 encoding of `test<newline>`.

Comment: This is a really great answer, thank you. To be clear, unlike `cmd <<< 'something'`, doing `printf '%s\n' "$something" | cmd` doesn't write any data to the disk or /tmp, right?

Comment: @user318418, yes, unless `cmd` writes it to disk itself. The data may also end up written to disk if memory pages of the shell or of `cmd` that contain that data are swapped out to disk under memory pressure.

Comment: Where can I learn more about executing and piping commands without writing to the disk or "disk memory pages of the shell"?

Comment: @user318418, [swapping to disk when the system is low on memory or for putting RAM to better use is a generic feature of most modern OSes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging#Unix_and_Unix-like_systems). If you're concerned about that, best  is to use full disk encryption, it's hard to guarantee some data will not be written to disk, there is some system API for that (`mlock()` and co) but shells generally don't have interface to that.